# Why use variable in model (MVC)?

Tags: php, joomla

I'm reading Master Joomla! 1.5 book, and I notice in the Revue model has a function like that

```
// model
function getRevues() {
  $db =& $this->_db;
  if( empty($this->_revues) ) // ?????
  {
    $query = $this->_buildQuery();
    $limitstart = $this->getState('limitstart');
    $limit = $this->getState('limit');

    $this->_revues = $this->_getLimit($query, $limitstart, $limit);
  }
  return $this->_revues;
}

// view
....
revues =& model->getRevues();
```

why use _revues variable in class model? If I remove _revues variable and rewrite getRevues function as follows:

```
function getRevues() {
  $db =& $this->_db;

    $query = $this->_buildQuery();
    $limitstart = $this->getState('limitstart');
    $limit = $this->getState('limit');

    $revues = $this->_getLimit($query, $limitstart, $limit);

  return &$revues;
}
```

what difference between 2 functions?

Comment: Revue is variable of revue table object.

Comment: Revue is a stupid way to write "review". This is necessary in Joomla as you cant use the word "view" in the name of a view class when writing your custom modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second one, you *always* execute the database query. In the first one you **cache** the results (in `$this->_revues`)which might increase performance of the application. So the database is only hit if you call this method the first time.